# Raspi - DBUS - Bluez: Method "GetAll" with signature "s" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, d-bus, bluez

I'm facing the following issue: I have an app that is written in Go that makes use of the bluetooth api. When compiling for windows and running it, the app works. When compiling for my raspberry pi, the app fails. I was looking around on the internet for some hints on what the issue might be. The app throws the following error:

```
Properties.GetAll org.bluez.Device1: Method "GetAll" with signature "s" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
```

Apparently when reading through the dbus documentation, that method should exist on that interface with the given signature. Therefore something is wrong - probably with the dbus installation.

I found some instances of that error occuring - but none are describing a solution:

- https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/460
- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/pc-config-for-bluetooth-not-able-to-d-l-anything-4175656862/

To help with finding a solution, I ran the commands given in the linuxquestions forum:

```
$ dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --type=method_call --print-reply /org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll string:org.bluez.Device1
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Method "GetAll" with signature "s" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
```

This says, that it is not an issue with the app, I'm running, but with the raspberry itself. Another app (written in Python) is able to create bluetooth connections successfully, therefore I'm ruling out a hardware issue.

Here is some more information about my system:

```
$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0     blocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye

$ apt -qq list bluez
bluez/oldstable,now 5.55-3.1+rpt2+deb11u1 armhf  [installed,automatically]
```

What is wrong with my installation? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have only wrong object path defined in your request. Optimally use following code snippet to get all objects in bluez service and check if `/org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx` really exists

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez  --print-reply /  org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue: While not necessary on Windows, the bluez implementation only creates the dbus path after a BT device has been discovered.

In order to connect to a device using bluez, the program has to scan for devices first. Once the device has been discovered, all the necessary interfaces are created.